# X,Y independent of Z. (X,Y) independent of Z?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

$(X,Y)$ is a two-dimensional random variable. Assume the marginal distributions $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Let $Z$ be a r.v. such that $Z$ is independent from the marginal distributions $X$ and $Y$. Is it true that $Z$ is also independent of the joint distribution $(X,Y)$?

I do not know if the answer is obvious and that is why I am so stuck, but I cannot see it.

Comment: The answer is NO and you can find an answer easily on MSE as well as  Wikipedia. Search for "pairwise independent but not jointly independent''.

Comment: The fact the marginals of $X,Y$ are *not* independent means you need to tweak the example @KaviRamaMurthy provided.